# Create a deep link to audio call in microsoft teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have an adaptive card and I want to add a button that has call functionality to a specific person in this card "the person is in my organization microsft team". How can I create a call via deeplink to audio call?

**Edit:** 
This link will redirect to the chat window with the user: 
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=
How can I do the same but for audio/ video calls?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the equivalent link for calls:

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=user@domain.ext

And if you're not worried about users who don't have the Teams app installed, you can try:

msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=user@domain.ext

This latter link will not go through the browser. It will however pop up a message requesting permission to open the app. Choose your poison.