# Microsoft Teams Deep Linking failing for Video and Audio calls

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm writing a react webapp that exposes AD-Online contacts and provides the ability to deep link chat, audio, and video calls in the Teams application. I have written the following function ([based on the MS documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445962/create-a-deep-link-to-audio-call-in-microsoft-teams)) to provide the url for the deep link.

```js
const teamsDeepLink = (user, type) => 
  `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/${type === "chat" ? "chat" : "call"}/0/0?users=${user}${type === "video" ? "&withvideo=true" : ""}`;
```

The output of this looks something like this:

Chat

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=<user's email>
```

Audio

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<user's email>
```

Video

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<user's email>&withvideo=true
```

This works ok for chat, but fails with a `There is a problem with the link` message for audio and video links. Has anyone got this working and how?

I have researched this as thoroughly as I can. I have found [a related but different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445962/create-a-deep-link-to-audio-call-in-microsoft-teams) relating to bots, but I'm a step further on from that -- I have the URL from the documentation but I'm getting an unexpected error.

Answer (score 1):

When we tried to repro this at our end, it worked fine on Microsoft Teams desktop but faced an issue on the Teams web application (as you mentioned).

For that, we have raised a bug and the concerned team is looking into it. We will get back to you once we have an update.

Comment: Do you have an update on this? And, is the bug-tracker public so that I can follow along and maybe comment?

Comment: Bug tracker is not public. We will let you know once it is resolved.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer - We have checked this from our end and it is fix. Can you please confirm once?